# Compile Objective-C with GNUstep

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I'm a newbie in Objective-C.  I'm trying to compile Objective-C with GNUstep but it's giving errors.  I tried to both compile on command line (gcc and makefile).

```
No such file or directory /
excepted '>' before 'GSPredicateBlock'
…
```

I used the command line

```
gcc gnustep-config --objc-flags -o hello hello.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -enable-auto-import
```

My attempt at using a makefile:

```
Making all for tool Hello...
Compiling file hello.m ...
hello.m:1:71 fatal error: ../../GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/Found ation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [obj/Hello.obj/hello.m.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Hello.all.tool.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

I've searched Google, but I can't find anything that helps.  I installed `gnustep-msys-system-0.28.0-setup`, `gnustep-core-0.28.0-setup` and `gnustep-devel-1.3.0-setup` on Windows 7.

Comment: Error is : No such file or directory / excepted '>' before 'GSPredicateBlock' and more. I use gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o hello hello.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -enable-auto-import in commandline

Comment: I would suggest writing a Makefile for GNUstepMake. This eliminates compiler commands which could possibly be wrong. For an example see here: http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/index.html

Comment: I'm try do this(Makefile for GNUstepMake) but it have an same error.What will I do? Tell me please.

Comment: When I compile hello.m it have an error and got hello.d don't have .exe.What about this.

Comment: Making all for tool Hello...
 Compiling file hello.m ...
hello.m:1:71 fatal error: ../../GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/Found
ation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [obj/Hello.obj/hello.m.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Hello.all.tool.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and add the code you want to compile together with the makefile you are using and the error output which results from running make.

Comment: Ok,Thank you all.It's just work fine when I'm reinstall again :)

Comment: The error messages in your first command are obviously copied manually, given the spelling errors. **Always copy-paste error messages**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a red herring but I see there's a space in a place where it should not be:

```
Foundation/Found ation.h
```

it should read:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

(without the space) in your source code file

Obviously this is what the compiler complains about here:

```
hello.m:1:71 fatal error: ../../GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/Found ation.h: No such file or directory
```

remove that space in your source code file's import directive and try again.